# How can a Sublime Text build system access the contents of a buffer, not a file?

Tags: build, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Let's say I open a new buffer in Sublime Text 3 (ST3); how can I access the contents of that buffer from my build system?  *i.e.* Let's say I have a build system that will run a file thorough `node`—in that case I can simply use `$file`, but as far as I can tell, there is no build system variable for the current buffer's contents.  Is there any way to pull the contents of the currently selected, unsaved buffer into a build process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to write a custom plugin to perform the build process, then add

```js
"target": "my_plugin_class"
```

to your `.sublime-build` file instead of the standard

```js
"cmd": ["external_program", "option1", "option2", "$file"]
```

In your plugin, you can then reference the current [view](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View), or even the current [window](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) if you have more than one tab open that you'd like to process. Your plugin could be as simple as writing the current view's contents to a temp file, running it with Python, for example, then deleting the temp file when you're done.

To get an idea of how the standard build process is executed, check out `Packages/Default/exec.py`. You can browse to this file directly in Sublime Text 2 by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. In ST3, all default packages are wrapped up in `.sublime-package` zip files, so you'll need to install the excellent [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. Once installed, open the Command Palette with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>)<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or **`Tools -> Command Palette`**, type ***`prv`*** to bring up the **P**ackage**R**esource**V**iewer options, select **`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`**, then go through the menus to select `Default -> exec.py`.

Good luck!