# How can i make shortcuts for partial build in sublime text3(program is python)?

Tags: python, sublimetext

Usually, i use  `ctrl+b` to build a entire python file.

But when i want to partial build, it is not a useful shortcuts.

For example, if i want to build only 3, 4, 5, 6 as shown below, i have to comment out others lines.

```
   """
    print("1")
    print("2")
    """
    print("3")
    print("4")
    print("5")
    print("6")
    """
    print("7")
    print("8")
    print("9")
    print("10")
    """
```

so, i want to make shortcuts that only build on the selected lines.

is it possible in sublime text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a Sublime Text build system access the contents of a buffer, not a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408444/how-can-a-sublime-text-build-system-access-the-contents-of-a-buffer-not-a-file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But I can't fully understand the content of your recommendation.
(in fact, i don't know well about build system or buffer... so on)

Is it impossible to make shortcuts by just modifying the 'sublime-keymap-user' or other simple way? 

Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: basically, the way the built in build system is designed is that it will work with saved files only, and not the contents of the buffer or selection etc. So there is no way to achieve what you want by just adding a keybinding, you need to use some form of plugin that the build system will use instead of the default behavior.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I learned that it is not simple matter. I will try to understand the contents and search that proper plugs. Thank you.